# Regex ignore URL already in HTML tags

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, url-parsing

I'm having a little problem with my Regex

I've made a custom BBcode for my website, however I also want URLs to be parsed too.

I'm using preg_replace and this is the pattern used to identify URLS:

```
/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/is
```

Which works great, however if a URL is within a [img][/img] block, the above pattern also picks it up and produces a result like this:

```
//[img]http://url.com/toimg.jeg[/img] will produce this result:
<img src="<a href="http://url.com/toimg.jeg" target="_blank">/>
//When it should produce:
<img src="http://url.com/toimg.jeg"/>
```

I tried using this:

```
/([^"][\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/][^"])/is
```

With no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit:**
For solution See the 2nd comment on stema's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
(?<!href=")(\b[\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?307lh)

To make it more general you can simplify your lookbehind to check only for "=""

```
(?<!=")(\b[\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])
```

See [it on Regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?307m0)

`(?<!href=")` is a negative lookbehind assertion, it ensures that there is no "href="" before your pattern.

`\b` is a word boundary that anchors the start of your link to a change from a non word to a word character. without this the lookbehind would be useless and it would match from the "ttp://..." on.

Comment: @Moe Then just simplify the lookbehind to check for only "="" like this `(?<!=")(\b[\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])` [Regexr](http://regexr.com?307m0)

Comment: That worked! I'd like to understand a bit more about the (?<!) assertion, any reading material that you'd recommend?

Comment: @Moe regular-expressions.info is in general a good place to learn about regexes, [see here the lookaround chapter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: This doesn't run on browsers except chrome. Throws error.