# Regex match if not after word

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex that's matching urls and converting them into html links.
If the url is already part of a link I don't want to to match, for example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

Should match, but:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">Stackoverflow</a>
```

Shouldn't match

How can I create a regex to do this?

Comment: Could you please post some lines of the input string? The second case should not be matched because it's part of an anchor tag or because it has been already matched?

Comment: Describe what should match. To work with regular expressions you must be as strict as you can. Ed: maybe ^ and $ will do the job.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex ignore URL already in HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567836/regex-ignore-url-already-in-html-tags)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your url matching regular expression is `$URL` then you can use the following pattern

```
(?<!href[\"'])$URL
```

In PHP you'd write

```
preg_match("/(?<!href[\"'])$URL/", $text, $matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative lookbehind to assert that the url is not preceded by `href="`

```
(?<!href=")
```

(Your url-matching pattern should go immediately after that.)

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=544944) provides information.  The accepted solution is like so:

```
   <a\s
      (?:(?!href=|target=|>).)*
      href="http://
      (?:(?!target=|>).)*
```

By removing the references to "target" this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/(?:(([^">']+|^)https?\:\/\/[^\s]+))/m
```