# how to skip link from function being convert href into another link

Tags: php

Below is my function to convert from url to link :

```
function url_to_link($string){

/*** make sure there is an http:// on all URLs ***/
$string = preg_replace("/([^\w\/])(www\.[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i", "$1http://$2",$string);

/*** make all URLs links ***/
$string = preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</A>",$string);

/*** make all emails hot links ***/
$string = preg_replace("/([\w-?&;#~=\.\/]+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?))/i","<A HREF=\"mailto:$1\">$1</A>",$string);

return $string;
}

function update_todo() {

    //var input
    $projects_id = $_POST['projects_id'];
    $content = url_to_link($_POST['content']);  // <----- url_to_link()
    $date_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


    $sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `doc_to_do` where projects_id="'.$projects_id.'" ');
    $sth->execute();
    $rows = $sth->fetchAll();
    $total_rows = count($rows);

    if ($total_rows > 0) {
        //update    
        $sql = "UPDATE `doc_to_do` SET content=?  WHERE projects_id=?";
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute(array($content,$projects_id));
    }
    else {
        //insert
        $sth = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO `doc_to_do` (projects_id, content, date_created) VALUES (:projects_id, :content, :date_created)');
        $sth->execute(array(':projects_id' => $projects_id, ':content' => $content, ':date_created' => $date_created));
    }
}
```

i try to convert my content that have url become link using function above. When first save the link look like this :

```
<p><a target="_blank" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">http://stackoverflow.com/</a></p>
```

when i try to save again the link will broken :

```
<p><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"<a target="_blank" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">http://stackoverflow.com/</a>\"><a target="_blank" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">http://stackoverflow.com/</a></a></p>
```

as you can see my function is not good enough, its should ignore link but convert url only

Comment: Why would you be doing it twice? Is there any chance there's HTML in the original text, or is this just a problem when running the text through the function twice?

Comment: * [PHP Regular expression to match keyword outside HTML tag <a&gt;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798829/php-regular-expression-to-match-keyword-outside-html-tag-a) and [Regex ignore URL already in HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567836/regex-ignore-url-already-in-html-tags)

Comment: @deceze see my full code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just strip link from my content first the create new one :

```
function url_to_link($string){

// remove all href to prevent duplicate(when convert) then create new one
$string = strip_tags($string, '<p><b><i><s><ul><ol><li><strong>');

/*** make sure there is an http:// on all URLs ***/
$string = preg_replace("/([^\w\/])(www\.[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i", "$1http://$2",$string);

/*** make all URLs links ***/
$string = preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>",$string);

/*** make all emails hot links ***/
$string = preg_replace("/([\w-?&;#~=\.\/]+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?))/i","<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>",$string);

return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't run the text through your `url_to_link` function every time before you put it into the database. Store the raw non-HTML data the user entered in the database and only convert URLs to HTML links when displaying them on the website. So only:

```
echo url_to_link($contentFromDatabase);
```

It's always a good idea to store the unprocessed, original text in the database and process it as late as possible. For one, HTML links are specific to HTML only. Imagine you want to send the text in a plaintext email or other non-HTML format at some later point in time; if all you have is the processed text you're in trouble.