# Find a word not contained in a tag

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make a regex that matches a word not contained in a "a" tag, I have to replace some terms with a link, without breaking links that already exist.
For example, searching for the term "stackoverflow", this should match

```
stackoverflow is magic
```

But none of these two should :

```
Jump to <a href="stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>
```

How can I do it ? Even if I use a HTML Parser, I still face this problem on how to apply my preg_replace on a term not contained in a "a" tag.

I've found this regex that sounded good :

```
(?![^<]*a>)stackoverflow
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't work in PHP.
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: See also: [PHP Regular expression to match keyword outside HTML tag <a&gt;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798829/php-regular-expression-to-match-keyword-outside-html-tag-a) and [Regex ignore URL already in HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567836/regex-ignore-url-already-in-html-tags) 
and [php regex to match outside of html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891771/php-regex-to-match-outside-of-html-tags)

Comment: A short but hackish way would be str_replace('>stackoverflow<','>9gag<', $url);

Comment: Use `DOMDocument` to extract text nodes and to search your word. To exclude text inside links from your research, use `DOMXPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your regex fails](https://regex101.com/r/hX2hA3/1) if there is any `a>` in the line.

---

Skip the links [like this](https://regex101.com/r/qZ0yX9/1) by using `(*SKIP)(*F)` verbs `|` match `word`.

```
/<a[\s>][\s\S]*?\/a>(*SKIP)(*F)|stackoverflow/i
```

`\s` matches a whitespace, `[\s\S]` matches any character.

Comment: `[\s\S]*?` is a trick only needed in Javascript, with PHP, use `.*?` with the `s` (aka `singleline`) modifier.

Comment: Thx a lot, works like a charm. I didn't know the SKIP trick (we learn everyday about regex !)

Comment: Is there a way to check also in the same expression if the word is not included in a <img /> tag,  ? I also have img tags, and same pb appears when I have for example <img src="stackoverflow.jpg" />