# RegEx - Match all URLs in string, excluding ones in <iframe> tag?

Tags: php, regex, url

I'm using MediaEmbed (https://github.com/dereuromark/MediaEmbed) to convert any media URLs in a string to their respective embed code, but it's also catching media URLs within iframes (already embedded).

The expression I'm using to match links is:

```
"~[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]~"
```

What would this need to be changed to in order for it to not match if the URL is within an iframe?

Comment: See also: [PHP Regular expression to match keyword outside HTML tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798829/php-regular-expression-to-match-keyword-outside-html-tag-a) and [Regex ignore URL already in HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567836/regex-ignore-url-already-in-html-tags) 
and [php regex to match outside of html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891771/php-regex-to-match-outside-of-html-tags)

Comment: Thank you, your references helped me come up with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution code:

```
'/(?<!=")(\b[\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/'
```